# Extend ribbon cable

Tags: cable, bus

> **tl;dr:**
>
> How do I find out the specification of any ribbon cable, like
>   *diameter*, *resistance*, and so on?

I recently bought a DRAC (Dell Remote Access Controller) for my PowerEdge2900 off ebay today. But as I just noticed (sadly after ordering) the bus cables will be too short to reach my motherboard since the cables delivered are those for the rack version.
But since plugs do remove pretty easy from ribbon cables I plan to enlarge them.
Given that I do not have the card yet, I would like to know what kind of ribbon cable I will need to do that, since I know there are different thicknesses of wires. Maybe someone with a DRAC is able to tell me.

Comment: You should consider whether it's worth your time. 60€ is about the same if not cheaper than the time you'll spend trying to manually modify the cables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it myself:

Ribbon cables are standardized by the AWG norm (American Wire Gauge). You can measure your cable with [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) table.

Comment: Do not remove the existing connectors and try to reuse them. They are not made to be reused.

Comment: You can buy IDC connectors from any large distributor. You will not have a reliable connection if you re-use old connectors.